# Migrate JAX-WS 1 WAR with Multiple Web Services to Multiple WARs with 1 Web Service Keeping Endpoints

Tags: jax-ws, war, weblogic12c, contextroot

WebLogic 12c 12.2.1.2.0
Windows Server 20xx

1 WAR file with multiple JAX-WS Web Services needs to be migrated to multiple WAR files with 1 JAX-WS Web Service each, for ease of deployment and minimization of downtime during deployment. However, this change must work with existing endpoints, all under the same context root, in order not to disrupt all the clients using the Web Services.

Example: Context root = /XWS, endpoints http://server:port/XWS/WS1 ... http://server:port/XWS/WSn.

WebLogic doesn't allow multiple WARs to be deployed with the same context root, so what's the best way to achieve this?

This is currently a pure WebLogic setup so we have no easy URL redirection facilities. Clustering/load balancing is considered for other purposes, but I would rather that the solution doesn't depend upon these.

Context root is either set to /XWS upon first deployment for each WAR or set in weblogic.xml /weblogic-web-app/context-root.

The log shows the following error:

weblogic.application.ModuleException: Context path '/XWS' is already in use by the module: WS1.war application: WS1.

I understand that multiple WARs can't share the same context root, but as long as all resulting endpoints are unique it should somehow be allowed.

Comment: Have you tried using partitions? Using partitions and unique port numbers for the partitions each deployed application should be able to run with the same context root. We have a few Weblogic MT servers that are setup that way and the same exact application is deployed to several partitions at the same time.

Comment: @ChadNC Thanks a lot for this suggestion, I wasn't aware of this new feature. However, if each partition must have a unique port number our endpoints would still need to change, right? Like in endpoints http://server:port1/XWS/WS1 ... http://server:portn/XWS/WSn If so, that would defy the point of the exercise.

Comment: Yes your port number would need to change but that would be the easiest approach and is a minimal change. You should be use OHS and mod_wl_ohs.conf to redirect but it's a real pain. The easiest thing to do would be to deploy a skinny war that basicaly has nothing but a servlet that listens on the original context root and redirects to one of the new web service war files based on the URL.

Comment: @ChadNC Thanks for the confirmation. Any change in the endpoints would require costly changes to a handful of external clients and I really don't feel like going down that road. Not sure a servlet redirector would be performant enough, potentially creating a bottleneck.

I'm very surprised that application servers lock you into a corner in this fashion. One needs to be very careful in planning Web Service deployments in order to avoid this.